# Catkin_Make Android_Core Error in Hydro

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the tutorial at

http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Rosjava/Android%20Development%20Environment/hydro

to set up my Android Workspace. I'm following the steps and I built rosjava. The very last step of doing 'catkin_make' to the android workspace results in this error

```
lucid@lucid-MacBookPro:~/android$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/lucid/android
Source space: /home/lucid/android/src
Build space: /home/lucid/android/build
Devel space: /home/lucid/android/devel
Install space: /home/lucid/android/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/lucid/android/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/lucid/android/build"
####
/bin/sh: 1: /home/lucid/rosjava/devel/share/maven: not found
make[2]: *** [android_core/CMakeFiles/gradle-android_core] Error 127
make[1]: *** [android_core/CMakeFiles/gradle-android_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

where is this 'maven' file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82121/catkin_make-android_core-error-in-hydro/) by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2013-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That implementation shouldn't be using the ros devel workspace maven paths yet (that is in the works). I've rewinded the rosinstall file to use the correct tag (see [here](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_tools/commit/382391c42702c3018c6c8a96e8ebb7ce8a56170a) so the roswiki instructions should work across chained workspaces now.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2014-03-09**:
link is broken

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-03-09**:
That functionality got moved to rosjava_bootstrap but this problem has been resolved for a long time now. Do you have similar problems with chained workspaces?

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2014-03-09**:
yes, i do.

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2014-03-09**:
Nevermind. Problem solved.